# Jquery mobile popup empty page with a circle when data-rel=popup added

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup

I am having problems opening a simple popup with jquery mobile.

When I add data-rel="popup" to my button the page becomes empty with a gray circle in the center.

Do you know what's wrong?

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title></title>
  <meta name=viewport content="user-scalable=no,width=device-width" />
                  <link rel=stylesheet href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" />
         <script src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
          <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
        </head> 
        <body>
    <div data-role=page id=win1>
      <div data-role=header>
            <h1></h1>
      </div>


      <div data-role=content>
      xxxxxxx
    </div>

        <div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar">
        <a href="#popupBasic" data-role="button" data-rel="popup" data-icon="plus">My button</a>        
        </div>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
    <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.<p>
</div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You're using old version of jquery, use 1.9.

Comment: that's the answer.thanks